# Cannot show @string

Tags: android, string

strings.xml :

```
    <string name="change">Change</string>
    <string name="Pleasechoosesubject">Please choose subject</string>
    <string name="onlyprovide">We provide only English version</string>
    <string name="action_home">News</string>
    <string name="creators">Creators</string>
    <string name="action_language">中文</string>
    <string name="version">Version</string>
    <string name="eEmailus">Email Us</string>
    <string name="contactus">Contact Us</string>
    <string name="About">About</string>
    <string name="ICTQuiz">ICT Quiz</string>
    <string name="EnglishQuiz">English Quiz</string>
    <string name="MathQuiz">Math Quiz</string>
    <string name="Tutorial">Tutorial</string>
    <string name="Opinion">Opinion</string>
    <string name="Home">Home</string>
    <string name="Help">Help</string>
    <string name="Exit">Exit</string>
```

other activity's xml:

```
  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/t1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingBottom="10dip"
        android:paddingLeft="7dip"
        android:paddingTop="9dip"
        android:text="@string/leaveopinion"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
```

Why I cannot show the words directly instead of @String/xxxx

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfPdW.png

Comment: This is because I cannot find a string with a name "leaveopinion" ? 
You didn't entered it in your string.xml.

Comment: have you put strings.xml in res/values folder?

Comment: Check that the field exists in your R.java generated class, maybe you need to clean the project.

Comment: My R.java have these fields, like  public static final class string {
        public static final int About=0x7f05000c;
        public static final int Back=0x7f05001f;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`leaveopinion` is not in `res/values/strings.xml`.
So first you need to add it to your strings.xml.
Something like this:

```
string name="leaveopinion">your_text</string>
```

And to display the real text instead of `@string/XXX` you need to refresh your_activity.xml .

When you did everything above it should be something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="change">Change</string>
    <string name="Pleasechoosesubject">Please choose subject</string>
    <string name="onlyprovide">We provide only English version</string>
    <string name="action_home">News</string>
    <string name="creators">Creators</string>
    <string name="action_language">中文</string>
    <string name="version">Version</string>
    <string name="eEmailus">Email Us</string>
    <string name="contactus">Contact Us</string>
    <string name="About">About</string>
    <string name="ICTQuiz">ICT Quiz</string>
    <string name="EnglishQuiz">English Quiz</string>
    <string name="MathQuiz">Math Quiz</string>
    <string name="Tutorial">Tutorial</string>
    <string name="Opinion">Opinion</string>
    <string name="Home">Home</string>
    <string name="Help">Help</string>
    <string name="Exit">Exit</string>

    <!-- this line -->
    <string name="leaveopinion">your_text</string>

</resources>
```

And check if you have put your `strings.xml` in the `res/values/` folder.

Hope it helps!

If it doesn't work try to rebuild your project.